# Error in Android Studio Terminal with Move Command [Access is denied]

Tags: android, json, android-studio, google-analytics, terminal

I am trying to follow the steps to integrate google analytics into an android app from [this site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/). I'm getting stuck at the point where I'm supposed to move the configuration .json file and whenever I try use the move command in the android studio terminal I get this result:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin>move "C:\Users\Nano\Documents\School\Programming\Game\android\google-services.json" \app
Access is denied.
        0 file(s) moved.
```

I'm not sure what to do, the other people that I've seen with this issue were on Linux and had slightly different issues. Any help such as a solution or technical resources would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin` and your destination is `\app`. Terminal will look for the destination folder in the current directory if you give just the folder name as destination.

You should **specify the full path to the `\app` folder under your project directory as destination** in your command.